# Fill the missing values in the data set

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science

I have a dataset as below.

```
building_id meter   meter_reading   primary_use square_feet air_temperature dew_temperature sea_level_pressure  wind_direction  wind_speed  hour    day weekend month
0            0  0   NaN 0   7432    25.0    20.0    1019.7  0.0 0.0 0   1   4   1
1            1  0   NaN 0   2720    25.0    20.0    1019.7  0.0 0.0 0   1   4   1
2            2  0   NaN 0   5376    25.0    20.0    1019.7  0.0 0.0 0   1   4   1
3            3  0   NaN 0   23685   25.0    20.0    1019.7  0.0 0.0 0   1   4   1
4            4  0   NaN 0   116607  25.0    20.0    1019.7  0.0 0.0 0   1   4   1
```

You can see that the values under meter_reading are Nan and i like to fill that up with that column mean grouped by "primary_use" and "square_feet" column. Which api I could use to achieve this. I am currently using scikit learn's imputer.

Thanks and your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pandas data frame, it already brings everything you need.

Note that `priary_use` is a categorical feature while `square_feet` is continuous. So first you would like to split `square_feet` into categories, so you can calculate the mean `meter_reading`  per group.